# ansible lookup pipe what does this pipe means?

Tags: ansible

In ansible, I can use something like:

```
debug:var="{{lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d')}}"
```

This can work, but what does the 'pipe' mean? cannot find any detail explanation for this in ansible document, want to understand what happens when this statement run.

For example, is the 'date' means run 'date' command from shell? and then use pipe-like way to format the date in the specified way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `pipe` is an ansible lookup plugin that will calculate the output of the shell command you specify in lookup's second parameter, and pipe it to the left side of your lookup. You can specify any shell command there.

Therefore in your example, the output of shell command `date +%Y%m%d` should be pipe'd to the debug module and `var` should be set to this output value.

I generally use `pipe` lookup to set a fact for timestamp so that I can append timestamp in a variable at the end for any resource names, like this:

```
- set_fact: timestamp="{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S') }}"
```

Official documentation on [Lookups](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_lookups.html), and specific example that includes [`pipe`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_lookups.html#more-lookups).

Comment: First example that I found that _does not_ use `debug`. Well done. Cheers.

Comment: Something to point out here is that the ansible var will be evaluated every time it is used. Hence, the timestamp can not be the same if using the variable multiple times