# How can i save new output file whenever runs a ansible-playbook instead of overwrite

Tags: ansible, yaml

The yaml file which given below can add the new output in a single file. But i would like to have new file whenever the playbook get run. Thanks in advance

```yaml
-  hosts: cpe_4221
   gather_facts: False
   connection: network_cli

   tasks:
      - name: show run
        ios_command:
          commands:
          - show platform hardware qfp active datapath utilization
          - show processes cpu | e 0.00
          - show platform software status control-processor brief
          - show platform hardware qfp active statistics drop
          - show crypto ipsec sa

        register: showoutput


      - name: save output to local directory
        lineinfile:
          dest: "/tmp/Traffic-Test-4221/{{hostvars.localhost.DTG}}/{{ inventory_hostname }}-{{hostvars.localhost.DTG}}-showoutput.txt"
          line: "{{ showoutput.stdout | join('\n') }}"
          insertafter: EOF
        delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a time and date to the filename for example. You can use the build in variable `ansible_date_time` for that.

These are all the formats available to ansible_date_time:

```
"date": "2021-09-24",
"day": "24",
"epoch": "1501173540",
"hour": "22",
"iso8601": "2017-07-27T16:39:00Z",
"iso8601_basic": "20170727T220900129160",
"iso8601_basic_short": "20170727T220900",
"iso8601_micro": "2017-07-27T16:39:00.129240Z",
"minute": "09",
"month": "09",
"second": "00",
"time": "22:09:00",
"tz": "CEST",
"tz_offset": "+0100",
"weekday": "Friday",
"weekday_number": "5",
"weeknumber": "38",
"year": "2021"
```

In your example you could add a date and time to the filename `dest` like so:

```
dest: "/tmp/Traffic-Test-4221/{{hostvars.localhost.DTG}}/{{ansible_date_time.date}}-{ansible_date_time.time}}-{{ inventory_hostname }}-{{hostvars.localhost.DTG}}-showoutput.txt"
```

If the playbook is only run once a day you could minimize to `{{ansible_date_time.date}}`

*Something to take into account:* the `ansible_date_time` var is set during gathering of facts. So it is a static value during the run of the playbook. If you want the exact time at that moment you could use a [pipe command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554281/ansible-lookup-pipe-what-does-this-pipe-means)